# New version of app gives error "Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uistoryboard

*Closed*

I have come across a problem that I can't seem to find the answer to. When I run my app as a fresh install everything works perfectly but if I first install the current version of my app that is on the App Store and then starts my new version of the app from Xcode on my device I get this error on startup.

What I've changed in the version I'm currently developing I've added a new initial view controller that is displayed while I load data from the server at startup and then show the view controller that was the initial view controller in the last version. In the last version this view controller, which is called BannerTabBarController, did not have a Storyboard ID and I guess that's what causing this problem but why? And most importantly how do I fix it without forcing my users to first uninstall my app before downloading the new version?

I have changed both the version and build of the app if that could have anything to do with this. Below you can see how I load my view controller from the storyboard and displays it.
Just to point it out again, the app works perfectly when running from a fresh install but not if I have the old version installed.

```
BannerTabBarController *tabBarController = (BannerTabBarController *) [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BannerTabBarController"];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

If anyone can help me with this I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the App Store version from your device, building the old version from xcode onto it, then building the new one onto the device?

Comment: Yes, that works but what if all users that are updating gets the same error and needs to uninstall and then install the app again for it to work? That is not a viable option.

Comment: From my experience, you shouldn't have a problem pushing this update. Things tend to break when building an app straight from Xcode on top of an app that was downloaded from the App Store. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I'll just have to cross my fingers then and hope for the best. Thanks!